# Angular: Align mat-grid-tile

Tags: html, css, angular

I am having some issues with Angular and their `mat-grid-list` / `mat-grid-tile` alignment.

My current html looks like this:

```
<mat-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="50px">
        <mat-grid-tile>
            <app-filter></app-filter>
        </mat-grid-tile>
        <mat-grid-tile>
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary">
            <mat-icon>document_scanner</mat-icon>
            <span>Export as CSV</span>
        </button>
        </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

Which looks like this in the browser:

[image]

However, I would like the first grid column to be aligned to the left and the second grid column aligned to the right.
Is that possible?

Comment: As a late answer: Simply reverse the order of the elements in your code. That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it via:

```
<mat-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="50px">
    <mat-grid-tile>
        <app-filter></app-filter>
        <span class="flexExpand"></span>
    </mat-grid-tile>

    <mat-grid-tile>
        <span class="flexExpand"></span>
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary">
            <mat-icon>document_scanner</mat-icon>
            <span>Export as CSV</span>
        </button>
    </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>

.flexExpand {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex. The issue is that the structure for [grid-list](https://v10.material.angular.io/components/grid-list/overview) is very much nested, so we have to use ng-deep to access the immediete parent of the content in mat-grid-tile.

```
.left-tile ::ng-deep.mat-figure{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.right-tile ::ng-deep.mat-figure{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ddktmr-utmzyn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fgrid-list-overview-example.html)